# How many touches can be detected at once by the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How many touches can be detected at once by the iPhone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the max is 5 fingers.

See this other Stackoverflow question: [How to force iPhone/iPod touch to handle more than 5 touches at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202484/how-to-force-iphone-ipod-touch-to-handle-more-than-5-touches-at-the-same-time)

Comment: It seems, in 2020 iOS14 has got the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

It's up to 5 fingers but "It’s important to note that the iPhone only keeps track of taps when
one finger is used. If it detects multiple touches, it resets the tap count to one." -from Beginning iPhone 3 Development published by Apress.