# read x,y pixel touched ipad/iphone?

Tags: ios, multi-touch

Is there anyway to detect which pixels you are touching while keeping your hand/finger on the screen (iphone/ipad)? Essentially drawing a shape of my hand (not as detailed like a fingerprint).

Thanks.

Comment: yes, there is a chance to detect the touchpoint. what have you tried to reach it?

Comment: i mean if i place my hand on the screen, can i detect every single pixel i'm touching, essentially drawing a shape of my hand (not detailed like a fingerprint)

Comment: yes you can get the point of the touches in case of one finger, in case of many fingers, in case of different touches... actually you can manage the exact touches in detail and depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is sadly not possible. The current devices can only detect up to 11 touches as **points** ([more info in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202484/how-to-force-iphone-ipod-touch-to-handle-more-than-5-touches-at-the-same-time)). There is no way to get the real touch area or the true touched pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the coordinate point of touch use following code.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"%f,%f",currentTouchPosition.x,currentTouchPosition.y);
    }
```

Comment: This would only draw a few points. I would like to gave a full map of all points touching the screen.

Comment: this is not an answer to above question